# ¿Como puedo guardar fotos desde Netbeans a una base de datos de MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8.2

Hola por favor quisiera me puedan ayudar no se como llamar a 3 métodos en una clase cuando doy clic en el botón de guardar quiero que me guarde, una foto en la carpeta del proyecto local y al mismo tiempo en la base de datos, ¿se si se pueda hacer eso?  dejo aquí el código de los métodos y como estaba tratando de unirlos si me pueden corregir lo agradecería mucho.

---

```
    //metodo para guardar imagen en carperta
public void GuardarImagenCarperta() {
    int pregunta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"¿Guardar Foto?", "PREGUNTA", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    
    if(pregunta==0){
        File salidaImagen = new File("D:\\personal\\6to semestre\\Base de Datos1\\Proyecto Final\\FotografiaCamara\\Fotos\\Foto"+contador+".PNG");
          try{
             ImageIO.write(ruta, "PNG", salidaImagen);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Imagen guardada en: " + salidaImagen.getAbsolutePath());
        }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.print("Error" + e);
            }
        lblFotoTomada.setIcon(null);
        btnGuardarFoto.setEnabled(false);
        btnCapturaFoto.setText("Capturar Foto");  
    }
    contador++; 
}

  //metodo para guardar imagen en Mysql

  public void GuardarImagen() {
    if (txt_nombre.getText().equals("")) {
        txt_nombre.setBackground(Color.red);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes llenar todos los campos");
    } else {
        String nombre;
        nombre = txt_nombre.getText().trim();

        try {
            try (Connection cn = Conectar.conectar()) {
                PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("insert into fotos values (?,?,?)");            
                pst.setInt(1, 0);
                pst.setString(2, nombre);
                pst.setBlob(3, fis, longitudBytes);                 
                pst.executeUpdate();
            }
            Limpiar();
            txt_nombre.setBackground(Color.green);
            lblFotoTomada.setText("Foto");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Exitoso");  
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al guardar foto " + e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡Error al guardar foto!!");
        }
    }
}

//metodo Limpiar

public void Limpiar(){
    txt_nombre.setText("");
    lblFotoTomada.setText("Foto");
}
```

//

Comment: ¿Dónde declaras y asignas `fis`?

Comment: fajiste que lo declaro como metodo al inicio del programa pero lo asigno en cadad jbottom son dos pero me pidieron que lo uniera en uno solo

Comment: Nos podrías compartir por favor los pasos a seguir por la persona que estaría ejecutando el programa, algo como:  - se inicia el programa, el programa pide una ruta (o pide una imagen o muestra el directorio por defecto donde están las imágenes, etc), el usuario selecciona una imagen (o la elige de las que le muestra el programa, o la sube desde el dialogo que muestra el programa), etc para entender bien como es la secuencia lógica de lo que tienes que realizar.  Favor de ser claro, de no obviar nada y de indicar que debe hacer el programa ante los posibles errores que surjan en cada paso.

Comment: Es un requerimiento extraño que te pidan unir esos métodos. Si necesitaras usar ambos métodos por separado en algún contexto no podrías. Lo propio sería dejarlos así y crear otro método `guardarImagenEnAmbos()` desde el cual llames a los dos métodos. De todos modos, si debes unirlos, dentro del `try` de `GuardarImagenCarperta()` puedes llamar a `GuardarImagen()` o poner directamente todo el bloque de `GuardarImagen()` ahí. Pero te digo que es una mala práctica unir métodos.